# Black lines and white dots after installation

Tags: monitor

I just put ubuntu 14.04 lts on another desktop, it loads all the way up, once it comes to home screen the monitor after a few seconds goes to black lines and white dots ,can someone tell me what might be the problem

Comment: We need some information. System, graphics card etc.
If that happens, press CTRL+ALT+F1 and tell what happens.

Comment: Can you take a picture of the monitor displaying the problem as well as @davidbaumann's suggestion?